# How can I make global a variable in a function m.file?

Tags: matlab

I made global a variable in main m.file and used that variable in a function m.file and I had no problem. But, I wanna make global a variable in function m.file and use that variable in main m.file. 
For this aim, I wrote:

```
   function cost=MY_Fun(X)
   global m
   .
   .
   end
```

in function m.file, and wrote "global m" in main m.file. But, I get m=[]! How can I do that, so that the main m.file could correctly find the "m" value?

Comment: global variable should work as you described. See if it is reset in your code. Without further description, that's the only advice I can give.

Answer (score 0):

In the main script, if you are using `m` before the function call to `MY_Fun`, it would be empty. But after it, would have the value assigned inside `MY_Fun`. `m` would get the value from `MY_Fun`, only after the function gets called from the main script. The following codes might help you understand.

**Main Script**

```
global m

m_before_fun = m
cost1=MY_Fun(1);
m_after_fun = m
```

**Function**

```
function cost=MY_Fun(X)

%%// Declare m as a global variable
global m

%%// Assign some value to m
m = 10;

cost = 1;

return;  %%// I prefer RETURN to END
```

**Output**

```
m_before_fun =
     []

m_after_fun =
    10
```

Comment: Is there a way which can get the "m" value in main script, before calling the function name?

Comment: @skbn Don't think so.

Comment: @skbn You understand that's against logic, as the execution flows through the main script from top to bottom unless a function is called, at which point it branches off and then comes back after the called function ends. Thus, there's no way you would get `m` as `10` before the function is called in the above example.

Comment: You are right. X in My_Fun(X) varies with m, therefore I had problem. I changed my program through ,and my problem had been solved.Thank you so much.